# How to add string to file using sed instead of from file

Tags: bash, sed

```
red    
blue    
water    
gray    
white
```

I want to use

`sed '/blue/,/gray/!b;//!d;/blue/r file2' file1`

As mentioned in this [Replace text between two lines with contents of a file stored in a variable in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574862/replace-text-between-two-lines-with-contents-of-a-file-stored-in-a-variable-in-s) thread

But instead of `file2` i want to enter new string directly in command. Can any one show me how to do that.

Comment: You mean you want to apply the `sed` operation on a output of a command? Can you explain more?

Comment: @Inian No. I don't want to  get new content from `file2` but instead directly put string(new text) in this `sed '/blue/,/gray/!b;//!d;/blue/r file2' file1` I dont know the syntax for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '/blue/,/gray/!b;//!d;/blue/a SOMEDATA' file
```

From `man sed`:

```
a \
  text
```

Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.

Another example:

```
$ sed '/blue/,/gray/!b;//!d;/blue/a \
> LINE 1 \
> LINE 2 \
> LINE 3' file

red    
blue    
LINE 1 
LINE 2 
LINE 3
gray    
white
```

Comment: yes it worked. so, Is it  `/a` for append and `/r` for read from file?