# Bash: Update file, and reference it in .bashrc

Tags: bash, file

I'm currently hosting a Github project that modifies the ~/.bashrc file. With the project being continuously updated, I'll need to know how to update the ~/.bashrc file without completely breaking it. As common courtesy and to prevent confusion, the changes I made start with

```
########## Added by Bash-Shortcuts ##########
```

and end with

```
######### End. https://github.com/OoLunar/Bash-Shortcuts/ ##########
```

Not quite sure how to go upon this, ideas?

**EDIT**:
I ended up using @reichhart's answer, and added the line:

```
test -r ~/.Bash-Shortcuts/.commandsrc && . ~/.Bash-Shortcuts/.commandsrc
```

This solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but why not use `source` to add new commands to your .bashrc file?

Comment: I didn't even know about that. I honestly thought that source was just a thing to reload the config to system... I'll look into further detail.

Comment: Take a look at `sed`.

Comment: See: [Replace text between two lines with contents of a file stored in a variable in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46574862/3776858)

Comment: @reichhart, Is it possible to reference another config through .bashrc? I am adding commands for the user to use, not editing .bashrc for some other means.

Comment: That's what @eduffy meant by `source` or `.`. You can simply put a line in the `.bashrc` like e.g. `. /home/user/.myapplicationrc`. Simply a dot (or `source`) then a space and the file name. I used here absolute filename because it _could_ be that `/home/user` is _not_ the working directory.

Comment: Ahhh, alright. So you're saying, instead of putting the functions and aliases directly into .bashrc, I could reference them by putting the line `./etrc/bash-shortcuts.d/` into .bashrc, which would prevent the bashrc from being broken.

Comment: No, `/etc/xxxx.d` dirs were just examples to explain the solution approach. If your application is running as user `user123` and the user `user123` should be able to modify it then the file should be located in `/home/user123` (or `/Users/user123` on macOS). Don't put it somewhere below `/etc`. If this would be a solution for you then rephrase your question and I will give an answer with description for also detecting already included file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution approach: sed or other inplace processes**

Possible issue here: The process modifying .bashrc can crash and then the .bashrc could be broken.

**Better solution approach: `source` an external file.**

Assuming: Application is called `myapplication` and it runs as user `user123`. The home directories are below `/home` like on e.g. Linux (macOS: `/Users`).

1. Create file `~user123/.myapplicationrc` (resolves to `/home/user123/.myapplicationrc`). Put all commands/configs for Application here. Make it at least readable for `user123` (execution bit is NOT required).
2. Add this line to `~user123/.bashrc` (is `/home/user123/.bashrc`) -- best at the end of the file: `test -r ~/.myapplicationrc && . ~/.myapplicationrc`  *(A dot, a space and then the file name.)*
3. Optionally: On your install code make a check if the line does already exist in `.bashrc` and add it if misssing: `fgrep -q .myapplicationrc ~user123/.bashrc || echo 'test -r ~/.myapplicationrc && . ~/.myapplicationrc' >>~user123/.bashrc`

More details: [Replacement for source in sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732200/replacement-for-source-in-sh)

**EDIT**: Use `~` instead of `/home/...`. This "tilde expansion" does not work in older Bourne or Heirloom Shells. But all modern Shells including small shells like e.g. Almquist Shell support it. On macOS it also works fine but resolves to `/Users/...`.

Comment: In step 2, I'd recommend using `[ -e "$HOME/.myapplicationrc" ] && . "$HOME/.myapplicationrc"` -- that way it doesn't have a hardcoded path, and it'll fail cleanly if someone deletes there . myapplicationrc file.

Comment: It was intended to _NOT_ use `PATH` or `HOME` as dependency because I don't know _anything_ about the application. On some servers I have hands on there are e.g. applications with reduced environment (e.g. `env -i`). But I will take your proposal and I'll add `test -r` as check. Upvoted your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @reichhart Hmm, I have the complementary worry that files (and home directories) get moved around and renamed, and like to write things so they're robust against *that*. How about a compromise: bash (but not all other shells) will expand `~` to the home path even if `$HOME` isn't defined (try `env -i bash -c 'echo ~'`), so `test -r ~/. myapplicationrc && . ~/myapplicationrc` should work in both situations.